# How to scale a text object?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

```
var loginText = new Kinetic.Text({
                  x: 5,
                  y: 5,
                  text: 'login: someLogin',
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontFamily: 'Arial',
                  fill: 'green'
                });
loginText.scaleX(4);
loginText.scaleY(4);
```

I'am trying to scale a Kinetic.Text object, but nothing happens, I don't know if its possible, I've also tried this:

```
loginText.fillPatternScale({
  x: 4
  y: 4
});
```

but still nothings happens, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by markE should work.

Here is the complete code and a fiddle example where you can see it work: http://jsfiddle.net/J8vju/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    container: 'container'
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var loginText = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 5,
    y: 5,
    text: 'login: someLogin',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fill: 'green'
});

var loginText2 = loginText.clone({y: 200});

loginText.scaleX(4);
loginText.scaleY(4);

layer.add(loginText);
layer.add(loginText2);
stage.add(layer);
stage.draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add the text object to the layer and then `layer.draw` to redisplay the layer:

```
var loginText = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 5,
    y: 5,
    text: 'login: someLogin',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fill: 'green'
});
loginText.scaleX(4);
loginText.scaleY(4);

layer.add(loginText);

layer.draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: before scaling Pic]scaleX should work check out this example [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-text-tutorial/) just add this line

```
simpleText.scaleX(2);
```

as line number thirty(30) to this example. You will see the scaleX effect on the text working in the example.Make sure you are scaling it before adding line to the layar.Hope that helps.

[image: After scaling pic]

Comment: it is setting the offset not the scale, simpleText.offsetX(simpleText.width()/2);, I've tried scaleX and after that redrawed my layer, but still nothing happens

Comment: @user3414354 have you checked out the example mentioned above and made the above mentioned changes?.

Comment: @user3414354 I am seeing the scaling in x direction after i am making above mentioned changes in the example. check out the pics in the updated answer